# What happens when we discharge a capacitor through a SCR which we leave open?

Tags: capacitor, current, switches, thyristor, scr

I am wondering what would happen when we discharge a capacitor, by using a SCR, through a coil and we leave a current applied to the gate of the SCR. The coil should generate a ‘reverse’ current right? Can this current go through the still open SCR or is this not possible because the SCR consists of diodes, which only let current in from one direction? (We have placed a flyback-diode in series with a resistor in parallel of the coil, if this would make a difference.)

Comment: For clarity, add a schematic. There's a schematic drawing tool available when you edit your question.

Comment: My bad, I’m currently writing this using my phone and I’ve got the schematics at home on my laptop. I will add them when I get home.

Comment: No, a coil doesn’t generate a reverse current. Walk before you run.

Comment: With reverse current I meant the inductive spike when the supply current is cut off by the SCR, sorry for being unclear. If we keep the SCR open then this will not occur, right? So thereby I do not need to worry about any current going through the SCR?

Answer (score 0):

The coil will make the current continue after the capacitor has completely discharged, causing the capacitor to recharge with the opposite voltage polarity. When the capacitor voltage matches the inductor voltage, it will start to discharge back through the inductor, but the current will be blocked by the SCR. The inductor current will continue through the flyback diode and resistor until the energy in the inductor is dissipated.

Answer (score 0):

Just place a diode in reverse polarity across the relay coil. This will suppress the voltage spike from the coil.

Answer (score 0):

SCRs are non-conductive in the reverse direction (after the recovery time t<sub>q</sub> if previously forward-conducting); leaving gate current active during reverse bias only increases leakage current.  It is recommended to disable gate drive for this reason, but not strictly required.

Typically, a capacitor-discharge circuit uses an anti-parallel diode, keeping SCR reverse voltage minimal and extending the discharge through approximately one full cycle (the capacitor is returned to a positive voltage, somewhat below initial due to lost energy).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAbKPP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

As a schematic was not provided, I'm assuming this is what was meant from the description.